# How does a consensus algorithm guarantee consistency?

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, handshake, paxos, consensus

How does a consensus algorithm like [**Paxos**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_algorithm) "guarantee safety (freedom from inconsistency)" when [**two generals**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem) prove the "impossibility of designing algorithms to safely agree"?

When I consider the simplest case of getting two servers to either (1) reliably exchange a number (ie, both servers end up knowing the other definitely received the number) or (2) both servers end up knowing the exchange failed and don't change their state, it would seem that (like the two generals) message failure could always happen in a way that left an inconsistency (ie, one server thinks the other finished the exchange, but it didn't).

So how does Paxos (or anything else) really guarantee "freedom from inconsistency"?  Is there an explanation in simple language?  What's the simplest pseudo-code demonstrating two servers doing a guaranteed exchange, or completely abandoning the exchange on failure?

Comment: The papers by Leslie Lamport are available online. I suggest you try to read them first.

Comment: I've tried.  Hence my request for "simple language".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crux is this assumption by Paxos:

Liveness(C;L): If value C has been proposed, then eventually learner L will learn some value (**if sufficient processors remain non-faulty**).

The bad case for the two generals problem are when messengers are continuously intercepted.  The "if sufficient processors remain non-faulty" part eliminates that possibility.

In other words, if messages are continuously dropped then Paxos is not required to (and won't) finish.

Comment: Another way to look at it:  if the network is down, you obviously have no chance at all to reach agreement.  Common sense therefore dictates that analysis of any consensus algorithm must make some assumption about the availability of message passing... which in this case (IIRC) is encoded in the definition of a "non-faulty processor".

Comment: I still don't understand how the other components/recipients all know there have been no faults.  Even when messages _aren't_ lost, how do the two generals _know_ both received confirmation?  My understanding of the two generals "paradox" is that final confirmation is not actually possible.  So, even when messages aren't lost, how does Paxos do what the two generals can't?

Comment: Paxos doesn't know that the final confirmation made it.  It only knows that the generals will either A) never reach a decision or B) reach the same decision as every other general.  (And A cannot happen if messages eventually get through.)  In that sense it is solving a weaker problem than the two generals problem.

Comment: The consensus in Two Generals Problem ,being a "common knowledge" in logic, is different from the one paxos reaches,  more resembling to normal "knowledge" in logic and Paxos equals these two by presuming that learner will eventually learn.

Answer (score 1):

Paxos doesn't actually solve the 2 generals problem.  As quoted from the wikipedia article:

> In general, a consensus algorithm can make progress using 2F+1 processors despite the simultaneous failure of any F processors.

In the 2 generals problem, handling a failure of 1 node would mean that you would need `2*1 + 1 = 3` nodes to handle that many failures. The impossibility of the 2 generals problem is not generalized to N generals.

One way people solve the 2 generals problem in the real world is [fencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencing_%28computing%29).

Comment: You're wrong. Even there's three generals, they could not make their censensus a comm knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of the question: You are generalising 2 general problem as a base for N general problem.

Here is the problem with that: 2, 3 general problems are proven to never reach a proper solution. This is because each of them have no way of verifying who is right. However, this changes when the number of generals in question is 4 or more. As long as the number of honest nodes is greater than faulty, the honest nodes will be able to reach consensus.
The above condition is a very important property that makes a consensus algorithm successful.

Paxos or any other algorithm will have freedom from inconsistency if # of honest nodes > faulty.

When there are only 3 nodes in the network, it does not matter whether there are 2 honest nodes (which is greater than 1), the network would not be able to reach consensus until every node is honest.

I am unsure about what you are asking for in the secondary question pertaining to the pseudocode but if you want to know how a 4 node network with 3 honest nodes would verify consistency of data and reach a consensus I can elaborate on this.

Either way, an algorithm would only be able to have "freedom from inconsistency" if there are strictly more than 3 nodes in the network AND if # of honest nodes > # of faulty nodes. Satoshi mentions this in his paper on Bitcoin network.